# What happens when several remote concurrent connections to a H2 process try to read/write from it?

Tags: java, h2

I have read that H2 is single threaded.

If I have several thousands of users using my applications, there would be several thousands concurrent connections to my H2 process. If H2 is single threaded, does that mean that only one connection will be "worked on" (writing / reading the database), while the other thousands of users will have to wait for their own turn?

I was working on an online mobile game with this, but if the above is true, then naturally H2 is not a reliable option. So my question is: what happens when several remote concurrent connections to the H2 process try to read/write from the database?

Comment: You already answered in the question: *only one connection will be "worked on" (writing / reading the database), while the other thousands of users will have to wait for their own turn*. Use another in memory database.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza well I didn't know if that was true! Alright, I will look for another. Do you happen to have one to recommend?

Comment: No, I don't have one. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

H2 is not single threaded. It supports a multi-threaded mode along with an experimental (but working) MVCC mode and as such can work on multiple connections at the same time.

You should rethink your idea of having a connection per user, though. This is a bad idea for any RDBMS. Look into connection pools.